Stripe error: "You may only specify one of these parameters: default_price_data, type."
Attempting to create a product on stripe dashboard through node-fetch.
code snippet:
 async createProduct(data) {
      try {
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },

            body: new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(data)).toString()}).then(res => res.json());
            return { data: response };
            } catch (err) {
            return { error: err.message };
            }
        }

JSON Body:
{
  "name": "product",
  "active": true,
  "default_price_data": {
    "currency": "eur",
    "unit_amount": "1"
  },
  "description": "myprod",
  "type": "service"
}

without the default price data it creates the product normally, but it's without a price of course.
i need help with the JSON body to initialize properly the default_price_data stuff and in the future for similar data structures.

There is no "type" property when creating a Product.
https://docs.stripe.com/api/products/create
Can you share a requestId of the failure API ?

the type property is defined below as you can see and it says service. The issue here is that i can either define default_price_data or type. If i use only default_price_data now the response is:
        "message": "Invalid object",
        "param": "default_price_data",


Specifying type=service on a product is not something you should do if your API version is less than 6 years old, which I hope it is.
https://docs.stripe.com/upgrades#2018-02-05
You should remove the type argument from your payload, it should always be service by default anyhow.

yes i did, but now the response is "invalid object"
{
"name": "product",
"active": "true",
"default_price_data": {
"currency": "eur",
"unit_amount": "100",
"unit_amount_decimal": "100.0"
},
"description": "myprod"
}

That's because your parsing the top level keys of your data, but not the nested default_price_data dictionary. So the top level arguments are being passed correctly, but the default_price_data is passed as a JavaScript object. You can see this in the Stripe request log, also by console.logging Object.entries(data).toString()

yeah i fixed the issue by manually appending the JSON variables into a keypairs of strings and then send the new body.
